# Получение данных с акселерометра LIS2DH12 на микроконтроллере stm32 используя библиотеку "HAL", SPI+DMA

Tags: stm32, данные, spi, dma

Задача: получить с акселерометра **LIS2DH12** данные по **SPI**, используя **DMA**, то есть освободить процессорное время на сбор данных, ведь используется два буфера - один обрабатывается, другой заполняется. Известно, что в регистре 0x28 находится младший байт оси X, в регистре 0x29 - младший байт оси Y и т. д. до оси Z. Необходимо получить все 3 оси, т. е. 6 байт. Таких данных должно быть 2048, то есть объявлен массивы:

```
#define SAMPLE_COUNT 2048
uint8_t sample_buf1[SAMPLE_COUNT * 6] = { 0 };
uint8_t sample_buf2[SAMPLE_COUNT * 6] = { 0 };
uint16_t current_sample = 0;
uint8_t current_buf = 0;
uint8_t *sample_buf[2] = {sample_buf1, sample_buf2};
```

Суть в том, что я не до конца понимаю, как организовать прием-передачу данных, используя функцию-HAL `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi1, buff_source, buff_destination, 6);`. Должен ли я считывать 7 байт вместо 6, ведь первый байт - неверный? Должен ли я использовать режим **Normal** вместо **Circular**? К тому же, если я использую прерывание `void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)`, то код находится в этом прерывании 90% времени, что логично, но как реализовать иначе - возникает трудности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема была решена давно, но руки дошли поделиться только сейчас.

Цифровые акселерометры типа LIS2... имеют на борту **вывод прерывания**, в данном случае 11 (INT2) и 12 (INT1).
Использоваться они могут по-разному, в том числе для **уведомления микроконтроллера о готовности данных** (CTRL_REG3, бит I1_ZYXDA). В моем случае прерывание возникало через раз после настройки конфигурации датчика, поэтому для 100% результата о готовности данных нужно хотя бы один раз прочитать содержимое регистров OUT_X_L..OUT_Z_H.

После получения уведомления есть несколько вариантов обработки прерывания. Я копирую данные прямо из временного буфера (емкостью 6 байт) в основной буфер и инкрементирую счетчик измерений на 1. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_1)
  {
    if(current_sample < SAMPLE_COUNT)
    {
      memcpy(&data_buffers[flag.current_buffer][6 * current_sample], buffer.data_temp, sizeof(buffer.data_temp));
    }
    current_sample++; // so 6 bytes its 1 sample
    Accel_IO_Read(&dev_ctx, LIS2DH12_OUT_X_L, buffer.data_temp, sizeof(buffer.data_temp)); // restart measurements
  }
}
```

**Accel_IO_Read(...)** лучше использовать как нотификацию о том, что пора бы собрать данные, а не вызывать как отдельную функцию из прерывания по понятным причинам.

В данном случае я не использую DMA, поскольку для моих задач он хоть и дает рост в производительности, но дополнительно поднимает потребление энергии, что в контексте проекта недопустимо. Однако отвечая на свои же вопросы:

**Нужно ли использовать DMA?** Да, это ощутимо разгрузит процессор, но в отдельно взятых случаях работа с DMA может быть медленнее, чем без нее.

**Должен ли я считывать 7 байт вместо 6?** Да, первый полученный байт мусорный.

**Должен ли я использовать режим Normal вместо Circular?** Да, Circular режим в данном случае не нужен.

**Должен ли я инкрементировать адрес DMA?** Нет, поскольку LIS2DH12 обладает multiple reading (28 стр. datasheet), самостоятельно инкрементировать адрес периферии не нужно.

Алгоритм сбора данных по SPI с использованием DMA и прерывания по INT1 о готовности данных выглядит **примерно** так:

```
uint8_t buffer_source[7] = {0};
uint8_t buffer_destination[2048] = {0};
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    static uint8_t temp_buffer[7];
    temp_buffer[0] = 0x28 | 0x40 | 0x80;
    CS_DOWN();
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi1, buffer_source, temp_buffer, 7);
}
 
void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
    CS_UP();
    memcpy(buffer_destination + count_measures*6, buffer_source + 1, 6); // + 1 поскольку первый байт мусорный
    count_measures++;
}
 
int main(void)
{
    LIS2DH12_get_data();
    while(1)
    {
         processing_data();
    }
}
```

Чтоб в режиме Normal Mode сработал такой callback, необходимо **включить глобальное прерывание SPI**.